# recursive total of array elements equals target java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to total up the elements in an array and check whether the total equals the target which is this case is 24. the method has to be recursive,

here's the first method that requires a private helper method.

```
public boolean isSum24(int arr[])
{
    return isSum24(arr, 24);
}
```

this what I have tried so far. The total wont work. any suggestions?

```
    private boolean isSum24(int arr[], int targetSum) {
    int n = 1, total = 0;
    if(arr.length <=0)
        return false;
    if(n > arr.length)
        //break;

    total = arr[n] + isSum24(arr, targetSum);

        //total = arr[n]+ isSum24(arr[n-1], n-1);
    if(total == targetSum)
        return true;
    return false; //change this line of code as needed.
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: it is it not working, the row where im totaling up wont work

Comment: I think that you should calculate sum of array recursively then compare result with given number.

Comment: `boolean isSum24(int[], int)` does not return a number. So the line `total = arr[n] + isSum24(arr, targetSum);` does not make any sense to me. What is `2 + true`?

Comment: Thanks for the guide, makes sense why that return is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gustavo this is something you could do:

#### Recursion needs:

- base case
- induction step

What is your base case? You have the case where the array length is less than or equal to zero. What is your induction step? It is here:

`total = arr[n] + isSum24(arr, targetSum);`

You are running the *same* function in `isSum24(arr, targetSum);`, causing an infinite loop (or that's what should be happening).

You should remove `arr[n]` from the array, or use `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, stop)` to make a copy. Hope this helps!

> also, you will need to change your targetSum in the inner method.

---

This would be my code, if you really need it.

```
 private boolean isSum24(int arr[], int targetSum) {
      if(arr.length == 1){
              return arr[0] = targetSum; //base case
      } 
      return isSum24(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), targetSum - arr[0]); //induction step
 }
```

Someone format my code better.

---

First post. Comment problems to the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If we implement the problem in nonrecursive fashion -

```
private static boolean sum(int[] array, int sum){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        total += array[i];
    }
    return total == sum;
}
```

Now if we move the problem into recursive, then index and total has to be recursively incremented ~

```
public static boolean sum(int[] array, int sum){
    return sum(array, 0, 0) == sum;
}

private static int sum(int[] array, int total, int i){
    if(i>=array.length) return total;
    return total = array[i]+ sum(array, total, i+1);
}
```

Comment: I want to do it with only passing two parameters into the private helper method, just returning (arr[] , target).